# Is anyone aware of a Rails gem that is useful for displaying and paging through an image collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image

The results I am finding on the search engines are pretty much relegated to Paperclip, Rmagick, and other image processing gems. I have my storage down just fine, but I want to find a way that I can display images in a grid format, preferably page by page.

I could do a jQuery DataTable I suppose, I am just curious to see if anyone knows of something  that is specifically suited to images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really isn't anything special about paginating through an image collection.

Kaminari is pretty great for Pagination, then it'd just be up to you to define the layout specific to your requirements, which I don't think any gem is going to do for you.

https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari

Answer (score 1):

Not just for images but...

Both github.com/amatsuda/kaminari or github.com/mislav/will_paginate will do the trick I believe.

If you are returning activerecord object then kaminari is very easy to implement but only works with activerecord so it depends how you are returning your images. I believe will_paginate is more flexible